# Need Clarification of what "Authorized Domains" does for OAuth Consent Screen

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We received a message to verify our OAuth consent screen configuration for a few of our apps, because of a sensitive scope they use. We understand that and were trying to get them verified, but there were some enforced requirements that seem to have been added since last updating it. Now you have to have an Authorized Domain listed in order to support the Privacy Policy and HomePage URL which are also required. The 2 URLs are easily provided, but the Authorized Domains is a little trickier. We include the use of our Google apps on custom domains that our customers own. We can gather information about some of these but not all of them.

The consent screen does work currently, but we aren't sure for how long. We also aren't sure if we add Authorized domains and our customers are not included in that list if they won't be able to use the feature. Have others experienced similar issues to this and how have they worked around it?